# Is ArcFace strictly a loss function or an activation function?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, classification

The answer to the question in the header is potentially extremely obvious, given it is commonly referred to as "ArcFace Loss".

However, one part is confusing me:

I was reading through the following Keras implementation of Arcface loss:

https://github.com/4uiiurz1/keras-arcface

In it, note that the `model.compile` line still specifies `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`

Further, I see a lot of sources referring to Softmax as a loss function, which I had previously understood to instead be the **activation** function of the output layer for many classification neural networks.

Based on these two points of confusion, my current understanding is that the **loss** function, i.e. how the network actually calculates the *number* which represesents "magnitude of wrongness" for a given example is cross entropy regardless. And that ArcFace, like Softmax, is instead the **activation function** for the output layer.

Would this be correct? If so, why are Arcface and Softmax referred to as loss functions? If not, where might my confusion be coming from?

Answer (score 10):

Based on my understanding. The two things that you are confused about are as follows -

1. Is ArcFace is a loss or an activation function ?
2. Is softmax a loss or an activation function ?

## Is ArcFace is a loss or an activation function

Your assumption that ArcFace is an activation function is incorrect.
ArcFace is indeed a loss function.
If you go through the research paper, the authors have mentioned that they use the traditional softmax function as an activation function for the last layer.
(You can checkout the call function is [metrics.py](https://github.com/4uiiurz1/keras-arcface/blob/master/metrics.py) file. The last line is
`out = tf.nn.softmax(logits)`).
It means that after applying the additive angular margin penalty they have passed the logits to the softmax function only.
It might sound very confusing as ArcFace itself is a loss function,then why is it using softmax? The answer is pretty simple, just to get the probabilities of the classes.

> So basically what they have done is that they have applied the
> additive angular margin penalty, then passed the obtained logits to the
> softmax to get the class probabilities and applied categorical cross
> entropy loss on top of that.

To better understand the workflow checkout the below image -

[ArcFace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KoHG.png)

> I feel your confusion might be because of the fact that most people consider softmax to be a loss function, although it is not really a
> loss. I have explained it in detail below.

## Is Softmax a loss or an activation function

I feel that you are a bit confused between softmax and categorical crossentropy.
I will do my best to explain the differences between the two.

**Softmax**

Softmax is just a function and not a loss. It squishes the values between 0 and 1. It makes sure that the sum of all these values is equal to 1 i.e. it has a nice probabilistic interpretation.

[Softmax Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU9YY.png)

**Cross Entropy Loss**

This is actually a loss function. The general form of Cross Entropy loss is as follows -

[Cross Entropy Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGX8f.png)

It has 2 variants -

1. Binary Cross Entropy Loss
2. Categorical Cross Entropy Loss

**Binary Cross Entropy Loss**

It is used for binary classification tasks.

[Binary Cross Entropy Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0GKC.png)

**Categorical Cross Entropy Loss / Softmax Loss**

CCE loss is actually called the softmax loss.
It is used for multi-class classification because of the probabilistic interpretation provided by the softmax function.

[Categorical Cross Entropy Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHlbX.png)